# To many Redis connections

Tags: redis, laravel-6, predis

I want to use single redis connection in entire project is it right way to do this?
Because I am facing issue of too many redis connection when large traffic came into my site.

Comment: You should have one redis connection per client (or per thread).  You shouldn't be creating a new connection for each call.

Comment: @FrankYellin thank you for your comments. we are currently using per client  connection but still sometime too many connection made. Can I use redis pooling here? If yes, can you tell us best way to implement pooling in laravel.

Comment: Not laravel specific but you want to look into pconnect like in these examples https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/Redis/pconnect/php-redis-pconnect-method-examples.html

Comment: @FrankYellin when I using single connection for entire application get operation performing is quite good but set operation taking too much time. Should I need to create different connection for set operation or create connection for set operation per request or any other best way to do this ?